# Rescale a .ui window created with Designer

Tags: python, pyqt5, scaling, designer

I have discovered Designer and pyqt5 quite recently, and i am using them in personnal projets.
Recently, I tried to change the scale of one of my windows (.ui created with Designer) and it works, but without changing the dimensions of everything inside (buttons, labels, images, ...).

Every solutions that I have seen so far only explain the rescale of a window created only with pyqt5 (inside the main code), and without external ressources (such as images).

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this issue.
Also It's my first time using SO, so I may not be precise enough.

Firstly I used "self.showMaximized()" to change the scale of the window. It worked, but not for the content.

I tired various others programs but without any progress.

One of the possibility that I saw require to transform the .ui to a .py using pyuic5. I could obtain the .py, but could not use correctly because of the external ressources (from . import jj_rc I think).

Comment: You need to set a main layout for the widget (or central widget for Qt main windows). See the official guidelines about [setting a top level layout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html). Since it's the first time you've been using SO, please take your time to follow the [tour], read [ask] and review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).